# Reply with Gnus: `S L` vs `F`

Tags: gnus

With `Gnus`, I got into the habit of replying to messages with the
shortcut `F`, whether they come from private exchanges, forums or
mailing lists.

The problem is for the latter: when I reply to a message
sent by a person to a mailing list, `F` put:

- this person into the "To" field,
- the list into the "Cc" field,

so that this person receives my reply twice.
OK, I could use the `S L` shortcut instead of `F` since the
reply is then sent only to the list: so far, so good; or, rather, almost good.

The problem is indeed that `S L` is not very ergonomic and that
I have got too much used to `F`.
So I considered rebinding `S L` to `F` but the problem is that `S L` does not
work:

- nor for private exchanges (or mixed private/mailing list): no "To" field filled in,
- nor for the forums: `Gnus` tries to send a *mail* to the person and
  not an article on the forum.

The question I am asking is therefore whether there would be a way for `F` to behave as:

- `F` when I reply to a private e-mail or an article on a forum,
- `S L` when I reply to a message from a mailing list.